# Performance impact of stacking multiple Vue components

Tags: vue.js

I am building an application that uses Vue to display most of the data that my users will see (charts, tables, etc.)

Now, imagine I have a table built with Vue with a list of actions performed by each user. Now, the user name cell will be especially formatted with the user’s picture, social handle, etc. The way the user is presented in this table is the same as it will be in other components. It will also contain some especific functionality (e.g. hovering over the picture will provide expanded information about the user; but this functionality is only planned).

My objective is to reuse as much code as possible. This is why I was planning to have a small UserProfile.vue component inside my Table.vue component. Using this logic, I may repeat this for other information as well (think CompanyProfile.vue, ProjectDetail.vue, etc.).

Is this a good idea? Will it have cause significant performance issues to have multiple vue components inside one and other?

Comment: It largely depends on what state you bind from component to component.  If you pass a large number of props into child components that mutate often and force redraws of the child components, you could theoretically run into some performance issues.  However, the only way to determine if you hit that threshold is to work against a concrete example.  You're better off avoiding a premature optimization and focus instead on excellent separation of concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue has optimized the result of rendered html as far as possible. You don't need to worry a lot about it. Child components only update when their respective data has changed, that is usually quite cheap.

Good to [keep in mind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Authoring-Reusable-Components):

> When authoring components, it’s good to keep in mind whether you intend to reuse it somewhere else later. It’s OK for one-off components to be tightly coupled, but reusable components should define a clean public interface and make no assumptions about the context it’s used in.

For larger applications, you may use [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components)

> Vue will only trigger the factory function when the component actually needs to be rendered and will cache the result for future re-renders. For example:

```
Vue.component('async-example', function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Pass the component definition to the resolve callback
    resolve({
      template: '<div>I am async!</div>'
    })
  }, 1000)
})
```

---

I found some interesting topics that you might want to look:

[Performance for large number of components](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/performance-for-large-numbers-of-components/13545/9)

[Performance degradation when using components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5070)

[Unlock performance tracing in vue](https://medium.com/@brockreece/unlock-performance-tracing-in-vue-3b2c8f619cdc)

[Analyze runtime performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/)

So now, you know what to do. Hope, it helps.